# Checking whether the solution is correct or not and if correct then the bounds which would make it more strong claim

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

> During a month with $30$ days a baseball team plays at least a game a day; but no more than $45$ games. Show that there must be a period of some number of consecutive days during which the team must play exactly $14$ games.

- My Solution:Let the number of games played on day $i$ be $g_i$. Then, the total number of games played starting on day $m$, and ending on day $n$ is
  $$
  g_m+g_{m+1}+\cdots+g_n .
  $$
  Now, define s, to be the total number of games played during the first i days. That is,
  $$
  \begin{array}{l}
  s_1=g_1 \\
  s_2=g_1+g_2 \\
  \vdots \\
  s_{30}=g_1+g_2+\cdots+g_{30}
  \end{array}
  $$
  Now, note that
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  g_m+g_{m+1}+\cdots+g_n &=\left(g_1+\cdots+g_n\right)-\left(g_1+\cdots g_{m-1}\right) \\
  &=s_n-s_{m-1}
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  Therefore, we need to show that is that $s_n-s_{m-1}$ takes on the value $14$ for some $m$ and $n$ between $1$ and $30$ . What we're given is that the total number of games played on all thirty days is no more than $45$ , which tells is that each $s_i$ is at most $45$. Furthermore, we're told that the team plays at least a game a day, which means that $s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_{30}$ are distinct integers between $1$ and $45$ . The $s_i$ are going to be the pigeons in this question.
  Now, let our pigeonholes be the following sets:
  $$
  \begin{array}{l}
  \{1,15\},\{2,16\}, \ldots\{14,28\} \\
  \{29,43\},\{30,44\},\{31,45\} \\
  \{32\},\{33\} \ldots\{42\}
  \end{array}
  $$
  We're picking $30$ numbers $s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_{30}$ out of the set $\{1,2, \ldots, 45\}$. Counting, we see that that we have exactly $14+3+11=28$ pigeonholes, Therefore, some two of the $s_i$ are going to be in the same pigeonhole. By our definition, a pair of numbers in a pigeonhole differ by exactly 14 - this means well have an $s_i$ and $s_j$ such that $s_j-s_i=14$. But as noted above, this mean that the total number of games played on days $i+1, i+2, \ldots, j$ is exactly $14$, as required.

> If my solution seems right then , can we say that this problem is not having optimal values , that is we can have atmost $57$ games rather than $45$ since then we would be having the $30$ pigeons and $29$ holes ? Or we can have atmost $x$ games where $x$ lies between $1$ to $29$ isnt ? Not only $14$ isnt ? Atmost $30$ one not true for always and above $30$ too

Comment: I think you are right

Comment: Thanks ....Vezen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a flaw in your proof.  However, the following proof motivates the choice of the numbers $30, 45, 14$.

Let $x_i$ be the number of games that have been played by the $i$th day of the month.  Since at least one game is played each day and a total of $45$ games are played over the course of the month,
$$1 \leq x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < \ldots < x_{30} = 45$$
Define a new sequence by $y_i = x_i + 14$.  Since the $x_i$ are distinct, so are the $y_i$.  Moreover,
$$15 \leq y_1 < y_2 < y_3 < \ldots < y_{30} = 59$$
Taking the union of the two sequences gives $60$ integers between $1$ and $59$ inclusive, so there must be some $x_i$ and $y_j$ such that $x_i = y_j$, where $j < i$.  Since $x_i - y_j = 0, x_i - (x_j + 14) = 0$, so $x_i = x_j + 14$.  Thus, there is a stretch of days in which the team plays exactly $14$ games, namely $x_{j + 1}, x_{j + 2}, \ldots, x_i$.

Comment: If already we pick 15,29 then we have nothing left to prove otherwise if those two not picked together (one of those two may be picked) then also we are guranteed that there would exist two element in same hole isnt ? In my proof , so all fine isnt ?

Comment: Which ones may you tell i will explain ?

Comment: Yeah but whats the problem ? This whole proof of mine tells that in the case1: where 15,29 are both not selected (one maybe) ,then there exist other two which gives difference 14 , and in the case 2 : where 15,29 occurs both we have nothing to left to prove ? And these two are the only cases possible except if both are not selected which must have a hole pair by php

Comment: Thanks finally saw the edited version thanks for telling the motivation for 14 . And yeah can you once also tell if the optimal bounds are right of mine?

Comment: Your approach works for any number up to and including $57$.  It seems to me that the number $14$ was motivated by the desire to use the proof I gave.

Comment: I see thanks for explaining